# Declared a global variable in a .cpp file but I can't use it in another .hpp file

Tags: g++, extern

I'm working with **mlpack**.

I have a variable "traindata" that is declared as global:

`arma::mat traindata;`

in cnn.cpp .

Then I would like to use it in mean_squared_error_impl.hpp

so i declared it as:

`extern arma::mat traindata;`

But the g++ compiler compaints saying:

> error: reference to ‘traindata’ is ambiguous
>   beacause thare are 2 candidates, the one in cnn.cpp and the one in mean_squared_error_impl.hpp

( the last one is declared **extern**).

If you want i can provide the sources, write to fportera2@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the linker succeded in linking the variable.